# KendoReact DateTime Filtering

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, datagrid, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo-react-grid to filter Date and Time. I have created a component ColumnMenu with GridColumnMenuFilter as specified in the documentation [Kendo React](https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app/main.jsx). All the examples in their documentation showing date filter only. But in my requirement I need to filter both Date and Time with Logic (And/Or). Please look into the expected example image.
[image]

Please find the code below

Grid:

```html
<Grid
    data={result}
    {...dataState}
    onDataStateChange={dataStateChange}
    sortable={true}
    pageable={true}
    pageSize={8}
>
    <Column field="ProductID" title="Product Id" filter={'numeric'} columnMenu={ColumnMenu}/>
    <Column field="ProductName" filter="text" columnMenu={ColumnMenu}/>
    <Column field="startTime" columnMenu={ColumnMenu} filter="date"/>   
</Grid>
```

ColumnMenu:

```html
import * as React from 'react';
import { GridColumnMenuFilter } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';

export class ColumnMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <GridColumnMenuFilter {...props}  expanded={true}} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My filtering menu looking like this
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

KendoReact does not officially support date and time filters on grid cells (which are eventually filtered after specifying a filter to the column): https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/GridFilterCellProps/#toc-filtertype

The only supported filters are : "text" | "numeric" | "boolean" | "date"
with the default as "text"